# If finding a private key from a public key is [co-]NP-complete, does NP=co-NP?

Tags: public-key, complexity

In a given public key cryptosystem, if the problem of determining the private key from the public key is NP-complete or co-NP-complete, does that imply that NP = co-NP?

Complexity theory is definitely not my specialty.  I ask because from what I read that it seems that this would be the case (informally):

Determining the private key from the public key can be converted to a decision problem by asking whether a given bit of the private key is $1$.  The complement of this problem is then asking whether a given bit is not $1$ (that is, $0$).  For both problems, the entire private key is a certificate.  Clearly they are polynomial-time reducible to each other.

If either decision problem were NP-complete or co-NP-complete, wouldn't that imply NP = co-NP?

Comment: The title and body don't match. Also, you mean and instead of or? There is an answer in CS for this [intersection](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/what-do-we-know-about-np-cap-co-np), and this question might be asked there, too.

Comment: @kelalaka Fixed the title; thanks.  I think that one would imply the other, so using "or" versus "and" would be the same thing?

Comment: Or only false if both are false. So this has three sub-questions; the problem of determining the private key from the public key  (1) is NP-complete, (2)  is co-NP-complete (3)  NP-complete and co-NP-complete.

Comment: @kelalaka If either one is NP-complete or co-NP-complete, that they are their own complement (within polynomial-time reduction) would imply NP = co-NP, right?